# symfony 1.4 commandline not accepting arguments

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, command-line-arguments

I inherited a symfony 1.4 project recently and I am trying to make some changes.
I added 4 new tables and wanted to use the commandline tool to add the appropriate models.
Everytime I run the commandline I just get the usage output.

example commandline:
$php lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin/symfony -V

example output:
Usage:
  symfony [options] task_name [arguments]
...

I have no idea why it doesn't recognize the -V and give version information.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: You use English keyboard?

Comment: Yes I am using an English keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think register_argv_argc was set in the php.ini file.
When I execute with php-cli the symfony commands seems to work.